# Hibernate discriminator force = 'true' doesn't work with update query

Tags: java, hibernate

I have used `discriminator force = 'true'` and it doesn't work with update query. 
This works fine with `SELECT` query which use `DiscriminatorColumn` in `WHERE` condition but the same thing not works with update query.

Let me explain the scenario here with example:

```
class Employee {
    private int id;
    private Department department;

    //other fields and setters/getters

}
class RegularEmployee extends Employee {

    //other fields and setters/getters
}
class ContractEmployee extends Employee {

    //other fields and setters/getters
}

class Department {
    private Set<RegularEmployee> regularEmployees = new HashSet<RegularEmployee>();
    private Set<ContractEmployee> contractEmployees = new HashSet<ContractEmployee>();

    //other fields and setters/getters
}

<hibernate-mapping>  
<class name="Employee" table="employee" discriminator-value="Employee">  
    <id name="id">  
        <generator class="increment"></generator>  
    </id>  

    <discriminator column="class" type="string" force="true" />
    <many-to-one name="department" column="department_id" lazy="false" class="Department" />

    <subclass name="RegularEmployee" discriminator-value="RegularEmployee">  
    </subclass>  

    <subclass name="ContractEmployee" discriminator-value="ContractEmployee">  
    </subclass>  
</class>  
</hibernate-mapping>  


<hibernate-mapping>  
<class name="Department" table="department">  
    <id name="id">  
        <generator class="increment"></generator>  
    </id>  

    <set name="regularEmployees" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key column="department_id" />
            <one-to-many class="RegularEmployee" />
        </set>

        <set name="contractEmployees" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key column="department_id" />
            <one-to-many class="ContractEmployee" />
        </set>
</class>  
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Employee table:

```
id      department_id   class
---------------------------------------
1       1               RegularEmployee
2       1               RegularEmployee
3       1               ContractEmployee
4       1               ContractEmployee
```

Lets say that I am loading one department object with id 1 which have 2 regular and 2 contract employees. But when I am removing all the contract employees and update the department object like:

```
Department department = session.load(Department.class, new Long(1L));
department.getContractEmployees.clear();
session.update(department);
```

In this case, hibernate update query not adding descriminator value in where condition:

```
UPDATE employee SET department_id = NULL WHERE department_id = ?
```

which sets NULL value in to regular employees records as well along with contract employees records and this is not expected behavior. Later contract employees records would be removed by below hibernate query.

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE id = ?
```

Updated Employee Table:

```
id      department_id   class
---------------------------------------
1       NULL            RegularEmployee
2       NULL            RegularEmployee
```

Here, regular employees records became orphan children because of missing decriminator column in where condition of update query.

So is there any solution to achieve this ?